# Looping through array just printing classname@hascode

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to work through an assignment and currently stumped as to what my issue could be.  I've read through several post and attempted to resolve without success.  I know a lot of my code could be simplified, but this is a progression through the text so a lot of stuff has not yet been covered...

This is my Card class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Card {
    private int suit,face;
    private String cardS,cardF;

    // Default constructor to generate random number for face and suit  
    public Card()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        suit = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
        face = rand.nextInt(13)+1;
    }

    // Receive card and suit values
    public Card(int cardSuit, int cardFace) {
        suit = cardSuit;
        face = cardFace;

    // Define card face and suit values

        if(suit == 1){
            cardS = "Clubs";            
        }
        else if(suit == 2){
            cardS = "Hearts";           
        }
        else if(suit == 3){
            cardS = "Spades";           
        }
        else if(suit == 4){
            cardS = "Diamonds";         
        }

        if(face == 1){
            cardF = "Ace";
        }
        else if(face == 2){
            cardF = "2";
        }
        else if(face == 3){
            cardF = "3";
        }
        else if(face == 4){
            cardF = "4";
        }
        else if(face == 5){
            cardF = "5";
        }
        else if(face == 6){
            cardF = "6";
        }
        else if(face == 7){
            cardF = "7";
        }
        else if(face == 8){
            cardF = "8";
        }
        else if(face == 9){
            cardF = "9";
        }
        else if(face == 10){
            cardF = "10";
        }
        else if(face == 11){
            cardF = "Jack";         
        }
        else if(face == 12){
            cardF = "Queen";
        }
        else if(face == 13){
            cardF = "King";
        }
        //return cardF + " of " + cardS;
    }

    // Get numerical face value
    public int getNumericFace(){
        return face;        
    }

    // Get numerical suit value
    public int getNumericSuit(){
        return suit;        
    }

}
```

This is my DeckOfCards class

```
public class DeckOfCards {
    public static final int MAXDECK = 52;
    int remainingDeck,suit,face;
    String cardS,cardF;
    private int myCard;
    int cardIndex;
    Card[] cardDeck;
    public DeckOfCards() {


        cardDeck = new Card[MAXDECK];

        // Create array of 52 cards
        // outer loop cardSuit
        // inner loop cardFace
        int index = 0;
        int maxSuit = 4;
        int maxFace = 13;


        for (int cardSuit = 1 ; cardSuit <= maxSuit ; cardSuit++)
        {
            for (int cardFace = 1 ; cardFace <= maxFace ; cardFace++)
            {
                cardDeck[index] = new Card(cardSuit,cardFace);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    public String getArray()
    {   
        System.out.println(cardDeck[0]);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < cardDeck.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(cardDeck[i]);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String deckAsString = "";
        int i=0;

        for (int s = 1; s <= 4 ; s++)
        {
            for (int c = 1 ; c <= 13 ; c++ )
            {
                deckAsString += (cardDeck[i] + "");
                i++;
            }
            deckAsString += "\n";
        }

        return (deckAsString);

    }   


}
```

This is my main class... running both methods here have the issue.

```
public class MainDeck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DeckOfCards game = new DeckOfCards();

        System.out.println("test getArray method");
        System.out.println(game.getArray());
        System.out.println("test toString method");
        System.out.println(game.toString());
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What is your question?

Comment: Sorry... looks like I neglected to paste the actual issue....
The output in toString() is the class@hash representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your toString method in DeckOfCards is using cardDeck array objects and adding them to the returned String:

```
            deckAsString += (cardDeck[i] + "");
```

So you need to override `toString` method in `Card` class also and use it in string manipulations.

Comment: Unfortunately, overloading methods is not covered until the next chapter, so I have to find a way around this issue.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say 'overriding' methods is not covered until the next chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Please implement `toString()` method in your `Card` class also.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I realized that a couple of hours after posting...
Modified here:
  `// Define card face and suit values
  public String getCard()
  {
   if(suit == 0){
    cardS = "Clubs";`